# "This is an invalid script resource request." error when Websense crawls /ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, robots.txt, web-crawler, websense

I am getting the following error very often on my websites:

> "This is an invalid script resource request."

The error occurres when a spider tries to crawl */ScriptResource.axd* or */WebResource.axd*.

Disallowing these files in robots.txt works fine (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069072/scriptressources-error-this-is-an-invalid-script-resource-request) by TheLukeMcCarthy).

> User-agent: *
>   Disallow: /WebSite/ScriptResource.axd
>   Disallow:
>   /WebSite/WebResource.axd

This does not work, thought, for services like Websense that (rudely) ignore robots.txt.

Any idea how to stop Websense from trying to crawl those files?

The sites are developed using ASP.NET and HTML5 and hosted on IIS7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We're getting something similar. My only idea is to turn IP Address restrictions in IIS and then block their IP. (I haven't personally done this so it's just an idea.)

Comment: Thanks Tom. Your solution would work but I rather not block IPs since it is an error that really does not affect the user experience at all. It just offends my completism. I am just trying to learn to live with the error : ( Haven't found a way to fix it.