# This is an invalid script resource request

Tags: asp.net

I get following an error when visited web site on windows hosted server

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): This is an invalid script resource request.
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context, VirtualFileReader fileReader, Action`2 logAction, Boolean validatePath)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: did you get more information and ***troubleshooting*** ? more exception details ?

Answer (score 0):

turn IP Address restrictions in IIS and for more read from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069072/scriptressources-error-this-is-an-invalid-script-resource-request).